# How to transfer ownership of an extension without losing the download count in the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: account-management, google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

I need to transfer one of my extensions to another account and also need to keep the download count the same as it is right now. Is there any safe way to do it? By "safe way" I mean that it would be possible for me to ensure that my personal information will be sent to Google and not to a third party.

Comment: I really didn't get the PS part and the reason for the code... Have you read the FAQ?

Comment: You already asked this [question on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834731) You could have flagged it for a Moderator to migrate it here. I believe this has already been answered in [this comment on Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834731/chrome-web-store-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-an-extension-without-loosing-the-d#comment12532637_9834731) You need to use [this Google Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&formkey=dE9WRk93OGVyaEtvZzdoeGdXS2lvNnc6MQ&ndplr=1#gid=0) to transfer your Extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I deleted my post on Stack Overflow as it is almost the same question but they said me that it was more appropriate to post it here.

@Lipis : I was kidding, as a programmer I don't like to ask non-programming questions here so I put a little "code" into my question :)

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to transfer an extension by filling [this form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer).

Comment: the form has changed to a new URL: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/request.py?contact_type=dev_account_transfer